# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.Part

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I need upload file from html page and read it.
But exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.Part . 
in pom.xml servlet-api version 3.1.0,provided
My Servlet Import.java.In it upload file from html page and read it. But exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import com.training.Connect;
import com.training.User;
@MultipartConfig
public class Import extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)        throws IOException, ServletException {
    final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
```

Comment: Have you ever [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) an answer to one of your questions?

Answer (score 0):

You developed your servlet against servlet-api version 3.1.0 (which contains the `Part` class), but apparently your servlet container runs with a servlet version < 3.0 (which does not contain the `Part` class) and you experience the `ClassNotFoundException`.

So check the API version which is used by your servlet container and upgrade accordingly.

Comment: How to do it? How check the API version ? I use tomcat and the Eclipse.

Comment: @Dmitry88 from within `HttpServlet#init()` call `getServletContext().getMajorVersion()` or check the installation directory of your Tomcat (search for `servlet*.jar` and check its `META-INF/manifest.mf` which should specify the version).

Comment: I downloaded tomcat 8. In META-INF/manifest.mf  Java API for Servlets Version: 3.1 ...But it still does not work. But show exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.Part

Comment: so are you sure that your are using tomcat 8 when you run it from eclipse? You can still test from within the servlet, i.e. check `getServletContext().getMajorVersion()` (which must be 3).

Comment: getServletContext().getMajorVersion() = 2 .

Comment: How to check which tomcat I used in eclipse?

Comment: @Dmitry88 check project (right mouse click) / properties / server

Comment: Perhaps did not I install tomkat 8?  Window-Preference-Server-Runtime Invirements- Add- Apache Tomcat v8.0 - directory (C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28) - Finish   . correctly ?

Comment: simply try. At least this question is solved. Now you know that the problem is caused because right now Eclipse runs a tomcat with servlet-api 2.x. If you have troubles to start the right tomcat it is better to ask a new question...